# Включение или диагностика memcached на хостинге

Tags: php, memcached

Всм првт!

Захотелось использовать memcached. Ест-но все примеры из инета рассчитаны на установку сайта локально.. ну, посмотрел поддержку мемкэша на хостинге (phpinfo) - есть, и не на одном, но при включении - ошибки:

```
//php
//вот так ошибок нет
$memcache = new Memcache;

//а вот так выдает, причем не из блока die!
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("error");

Warning: Memcache::connect() [memcache.connect]: Can't connect to localhost:11211
```

Вопрос двоякий, в чем дело? В том, что я что то не установил на хостинг, или что то не так настроил?

p.s. гугл опять же вывел на проверку поддержки мемкэша - уже описал в начале поста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Осталось только запустить memcache-сервер. Некоторые хостеры предоставляют такую услугу. Либо можно поднимать свой на VPS.

Comment: т.е. по мимо того, что php поддерживает, нужно еще включить это как услугу на хостинге? т.е. на моем языке не в коде дело?

Comment: Да. Аналогично MySQL-серверу

Comment: Ох, а я что только не пробовал..  И абсолютный путь в место локалхост, и дополнительный порт, и хостинги все используемые перебрал. Буду знать! Спасибо!